# Titanium MobileWeb App - Flashing Backgrounds

Tags: web-applications, titanium, background-image, titanium-alloy

Got a very strange problem,

On my main window I've got a backgroundImage

However whenever I click anywhere on the screen, or try focus in textfields it just flashes

I've added a video to demonstrate its behavior

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W01vUQ_9DjY

the only styling on the window is this:

```
"#main": {
    backgroundColor:"#f4b7d1",
    backgroundImage: "/images/bg.png"
}
```

I've also tried

```
"#main": {
    backgroundColor:"#f4b7d1",
    backgroundImage: "/images/bg.png",
    backgroundFocusedImage: "/images/bg.png",
    backgroundSelectedImage: "/images/bg.png"
}
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem as well.

The root cause is that Titanium is reassigning the backgroundImage attribute after every click-event, regardless of if the actual attribute has been changed.

To fix this issue, you can hack Element.js file that handles the backgroundImage update.

The edit can be applied in one of two places (only tested on Windows, version 3.1.3.GA):

1. `%ProjectFolder%\build\mobileweb\titanium\Ti\_\UI\Element.js`

   Here we are editing the generated JS file and this will have to be done after every build. This option could be useful if you don't want to edit the actual Titanium SDK and just want the fix on your final build.
2. `C:\%USER FOLDER%\App Data\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.3.GA\mobileweb\titanium\Ti\_\UI\Element.js`

   If you edit this file, you are actually changing the Titanium SDK. You will only have to repeat this edit when you upgrade to a new SDK version.

Choose your file and then apply this edit starting at line 534:

Change:

```
bi = style.url(bi);
nodeStyle.backgroundImage.replace(/'|"/g, '').toLowerCase() !== bi.toLowerCase() &&(nodeStyle.backgroundImage = bi);
```

To:

```
bi = style.url(bi);
var currentB = nodeStyle.backgroundImage;
var ind=currentB.lastIndexOf("/");
var ind2= bi.lastIndexOf("/");
if(nodeStyle.backgroundImage.substr(ind) !== bi.substr(ind2))
{
       nodeStyle.backgroundImage.replace(/'|"/g, '').toLowerCase() !== bi.toLowerCase() && (nodeStyle.backgroundImage = bi);
}
```

This fix causes Titanium to only reset the backgroundImage attribute when the filename of the background image changes. Note, that this code only checks if the filename changes, not the path, so adjust your code accordingly if this matters to you.

This edit should also work on SDK version: 3.2.0 GA.